# Cannot install rdiscount 1.6.8 on Big Sur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am working on a project with markdown-rails which depends on rdiscount.
The project uses rdiscount-1.6.8.
I can install rdiscount latest, but I need 1.6.8.
Is there any way to install it on  Big Sur?

```
ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
...
4 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [rdiscount.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: This usually includes a line about where the actual errors are logged, so be sure to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:
This was the issue

> New in macOS Big Sur 11 beta, the system ships with a built-in dynamic linker cache of all system-provided libraries. As part of this change, copies of dynamic libraries are no longer present on the filesystem. Code that attempts to check for dynamic library presence by looking for a file at a path or enumerating a directory will fail. Instead, check for library presence by attempting to dlopen() the path, which will correctly check for the library in the cache. (62986286)

[Source and fix](https://thoughtfulapps.com/articles/rails/puma-implicitly-declaring-library-function-error)

I had to install gem with

```
--with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot